# Is it safe to pass an intptr_t to a function that expects an int?

Tags: c++, c, callback, function-pointers

More specifically, if I have the following function pointer type:

```
typedef void (*callback_type) (intptr_t context, void* buffer, size_t count);
```

can I safely and without "undefined behavior" do:

```
callback_type func_ptr = (callback_type)write;
intptr_t context = fd;

func_ptr(context, some_buffer, buffer_size);
```

?

Where `write()` is the system call (EDIT: has the signature `ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);`, thus takes an `int` as the first argument), and `fd` is an `int` file descriptor. I assume the answer would be the same for C and C++, so I am tagging both.

Comment: What you're asking seems to be the opposite of what the title is asking. Edit: Ah, the [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) system call takes an `int`.

Comment: Well, `context` is of type `intptr_t`, and is being passed to `write` that expects an `int`. Seems right to me...

Comment: Huh? At the moment you're passing an `intptr_t` to a function that expects an `intptr_t`. So where's the problem? What exaclty is the part that you worry about? The conversion from `&write` to `callback_type`, the conversion from `fd` to `intptr_t` or something else?

Comment: @lvella You didn't explain that `write` takes an `int` as its first argument. Does the assignment to `func_ptr` compile correctly? If so, then `intptr_t` must be `int` on your machine, no?

Comment: *"and is being passed to `write` that expects an `int`"* - Ah, so it is the function pointer conversion you're worrying about. Then this changes the whole meaning and title of your question.

Comment: @sftrabbit: The assignment involves a reinterpret-cast, so it will compile whether or not the conversion is valid. You'll get undefined behaviour if `intptr_t` is not `int`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ah, I didn't notice the cast. Well obviously the safe thing to do here is to store the correct function pointer type.

Comment: @sftrabbit *"Ah, I didn't notice the cast"* - And why, because it doesn't stick out as an obvious keyword everybody notices and understands (like e.g. `reinterpret_cast`), but is a name with some braces around it, like every third token in C++. Thanks for giving a practical example of the advantages of C++ casts ;)

Comment: I didn't use `reinterpret_cast` because the actual code I am working on is C.

Comment: Why so many upvotes, for a question asking whether it is legal to misuse an instance of `T1` to store a value of `T2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### No

That won't be portable because you are passing a parameter that will be a different size in the common LP64 paradigm.

Also, you aren't dereferencing the function pointer with the correct type, and the results of *that* are undefined.

Now, as you seem to have concluded, the function pointer will work as expected and the only practical problem is going to be: *how will write(2) interpret the `intptr_t` first parameter?*

And the actual run-time problem is that, on LP64, you are passing a 64-bit value to a 32-bit parameter. This might misalign the subsequent parameters.  On a system with register parameters it would probably work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at C standard.

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a
> function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
> equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call
> a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the
> behavior is undefined.
>
> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)
>
> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible
> return types. Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present,
> shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the ellipsis
> terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible types.
>
> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type
>
> Two types have compatible type if their types are the same.

Conclusion:

```
void (*) (intptr_t context, void* buffer, size_t count);
```

cannot be converted to:

```
void (*) (int context, void* buffer, size_t count);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with passing the argument back and forth between functions, since automatic promotion from one integral type to another is done.

The problem is, what if `intptr_t` is shorter than `int`, thus not every value of `int` can be represented by an `intptr_t`? In such a case, the some of the highest bits in the `int` will be truncated when converting to `intptr_t`, so you'll end up `write()`ing to an invalid file descriptor. Although that should not invoke undefined behavior, it's still erroneous.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of `intptr_t` is being able to hold both `int` and pointers?

Comment: @lvella the whole point is that it is an integer type which is guaranteed to be big enough to hold a pointer. But there is no guaranteed about what kinds of integers it is able to hold. The guarantee is just that the type itself is an integer type

Comment: @lvella As far as I know, `intptr_t` is an integral type guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer, and nothing else. Is there anything in the standard that requires that `sizeof(T *) <= sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @H2CO3 No requirement that I know.

Comment: @sftrabbit Thanks. Right, then this is a real problem.